# Configure complex schedule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm using [sidekiq-scheduler](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) and have the need to configure the follow schedule to run a worker:

```
Run each minute from 9h to 18h, but don't run at weekends
```

It's possible to do something like this with this scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's possible: `* 9-18 * * 1-5`.

---

`Monday` is `1`, `Tuesday` is `2`, and so on.
In order not to run at weekends, we'll run from Monday to Friday `(1-5)`.

```
# config/sidekiq.yml
:schedule:
  hello_world:
    cron: '* 9-18 * * 1-5' # Run each minute from 9h to 18h from Monday to Sunday
    class: HelloWorld
```